# Repeat event on assigned day every week until specific date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

When creating event I need to set event start and event end in datetime format (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`)
Then I have option to set weekly repeating of that event until specific date (`0000-00-00`)
But I can't insert repeating events properly in database. Here is what I have:

```
$startDateTime = '2015-04-30 10:30:00';
$endDateTime = '2015-04-30 11:30:00';
$repeatEndDate = '2015-06-01';
$timestamp = strtotime($startDateTime);
$day_of_week = date('l', $timestamp);
$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';
$repeatStart = new DateTime($startDateTime);
$repeatEnd   = new DateTime($repeatEndDate);
$repeatStart->modify($day_of_week);  
$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($repeatStart, $interval, $repeatEnd);

foreach ($period as $key => $date ) {
    $repeatQuery = 'INSERT INTO event(start,end,status,repeats) VALUES ("'.$startDateTime.'","'.$endDateTime.'","'.$status.'","'.$repeatEndDate.'")';
    $repeatResult = mysqli_query($db, $repeatQuery) or die (mysqli_error($db));
}
```

When I do `print_r($date);` it looks like this, no actual time just `00:00:00`

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-30 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

I know that I can't insert values like that but I don't know how to get correct values from objects.
So in this example I need to insert events that begin in 10:30:00 and end in 11:30:00(events always end same day) every Thursday starting at 2015-04-30 and ending at 2015-06-01. How can this be achieved?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `DateTime::modify` with a day name (currently 'Thursday'). This value is calculated from the `$startDateTime` variable, and then used to modify that variable, so the only effect it has, is resetting the Time portion of that `DateTime` instance back to 0:00:00.

The following gives me the results I would expect:
(I've commented out the parts you need to remove from yours, to make it easier to see the difference)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

$startDateTime = '2015-04-30 10:30:00';
$endDateTime = '2015-04-30 11:30:00';
$repeatEndDate = '2015-06-01';
#$timestamp = strtotime($startDateTime);
#$day_of_week = date('l', $timestamp);
$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';
$repeatStart = new DateTime($startDateTime);
$repeatEnd   = new DateTime($repeatEndDate);
#$repeatStart->modify($day_of_week);  
$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($repeatStart, $interval, $repeatEnd);



foreach ($period as $key => $date ) {
    echo($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The result from running the above is:

```
2015-04-30 10:30:00
2015-05-07 10:30:00
2015-05-14 10:30:00
2015-05-21 10:30:00
2015-05-28 10:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

When you modify your `$repeatStart` using the `modify()` method you are using the `l` format character which, according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), returns

> A full textual representation of the day of the week

by changing the `$day_of_week` format string to

```
$day_of_week = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

I get the following output

```
DateTime Object
(
   [date] => 2015-04-30 10:30:00
   [timezone_type] => 3
   [timezone] => Europe/London
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-05-07 10:30:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-05-14 10:30:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
) 
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-05-21 10:30:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-05-28 10:30:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
```

Although, the modification is not actually necessary and the following code should achieve what you are looking for.

```
 <?php

$startDateTime = '2015-04-30 10:30:00';
$endDateTime = '2015-04-30 11:30:00';
$repeatEndDate = '2015-06-01';

$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';
$repeatStart = new DateTime($startDateTime);

$repeatEnd   = new DateTime($repeatEndDate);

$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($repeatStart, $interval, $repeatEnd);
foreach ($period as $key => $date ) {
    $repeatQuery = 'INSERT INTO event(start,end,status,repeats) VALUES ("'.$startDateTime.'","'.$endDateTime.'","'.$status.'","'.$repeatEndDate.'")';
    $repeatResult = mysqli_query($db, $repeatQuery) or die (mysqli_error($db));
    print_r($date);
}
```